# Realizar un left join y asignar el valor de una columna condicionado por un campo

Tags: sql, join

Buenas tardes, tengo 2 tablas y estoy haciendo un `left join` de la `T1` con la `T2` para extraer el código de cliente. El problema es que existen 2 códigos de cliente para un mismo (RUC) en algunos casos (esto por la condición del cliente que en algunos casos tienen 2) y por consiguiente se duplican los registros en la `T1` ya que en la `T2` hay 2 códigos por ese cliente, solo necesito coger uno.

Presento el código para que me puedan guiar:

```
SELECT 
    '1' AS CO_TURN,
    '1' AS CO_ESTA, 
    '1' AS CO_FPAG,T1.CO_PROD, 
    '1' AS CO_EMPR,T1.CO_TDOC,
    T1.NU_NSER,
    T1.NU_NDOC,
    NULL AS FE_TURN,
    LEFT(T1.FE_HORA,5) FE_HORA,
    '0' AS NU_NVAL,
    T1.FE_EMIS,
    NULL AS FE_EMIS_HORA,
    ROUND(T1.IM_TOTA/1.18,2) AS IM_VNET,
    ROUND(T1.IM_TOTA/1.18,10) AS IM_VVEN,
    ROUND (T1.IM_TOTA-ROUND(T1.IM_TOTA/1.18,4),2) IM_IGV,
    '0.0000000000' AS IM_DESC,
    T1.IM_TOTA,
    '0.0000' AS NU_GALN,
    '0.0000' AS NU_PREV,
    T1.IM_TOTA AS IM_PAGO,
    '0' AS NU_LADO,
    '1' AS CO_TMON,
    'N' AS ST_DVEN,
    0 AS CO_CHOF, 
    CASE T2.CO_CLIE WHEN NULL THEN NULL WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE T2.CO_CLIE END CO_CLIE,
    NULL AS NU_LIQI,
    NULL AS ST_CANJ,
    NULL AS ST_LIQI,
    NULL AS ST_PERI,
    NULL AS ST_ANNO,
    NULL AS CO_TRAB,
    '0' AS CO_VEHI,
    'SISGES' AS CO_USUA_CREA,GETDATE() AS FE_USUA_CREA,
    '0.1800' AS NU_IGV,
    '' AS CO_TDES_DOCU,
    NULL AS NO_CLIE_D1_DNI
FROM 
    MAR17_1 T1 LEFT JOIN TCCLIE T2 ON T1.CO_CLIE= T2.NU_RUC 
WHERE 
    T1.CO_TDOC IN (1,15,2)
```

Comment: En tu consulta solo tiene WHERE hace T1; tu LEFT JOIN con T1 y T2 (considero) esta bien lo que falta es el criterio conforme al "motivo" de la consulta SQL debe cumplir para traerte un solo registro; te falta condicionar que registro de T2 traer para solo obtener 1; no es tu consulta es que te faltan condiciones para agregarle.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Ademas por favor **no uses mayúsculas**

Comment: Has intentado con GROUP BY T1.CO_CLIE; ?

Comment: Gracias a todos, al final tuve que hacerlo de otra manera, aislando mis consultas para cada caso, pero quería hacerlo todo en un solo query, la prisa era demasiada :/.

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo muy bien tu código, pero Pondré este ejemplo hipotético donde quiero sacar el total de ventas del cliente, sin importar su RUC.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asumiendo esta estructura de tablas esta consulta sql devuelve el total de ventas de los clientes NEo y SMA COMPANY.

```
SELECT
    SUM (Total) AS Total_Ventas,
    T2.Nombre AS Cliente
FROM
    Ventas AS T1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        ID,Nombre
    FROM
        Cliente
    GROUP BY
        ID,Nombre
) AS T2 ON T1.ID_Cliente = T2.ID
GROUP BY
    T2.Nombre
```

La subconsulta T2 devolverá los Clientes una única vez así tu join no repetirá los datos El resultado final debería ser como el siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias con esta respuesta aclaré otra duda más que tenía en otro caso. :D

Comment: Excelente, me alegra haberte ayudado en algo. C: